# Saving the deformations on an object after using soft body

Tags: soft-body

Once I have used soft body physics to deform an object, can I save the deformations on the object once the animation is paused? I am applying soft body dynamics, playing the animation and then pausing it at the moment I have the deformations I want. I would then like to further edit the object and position it in its deformed state. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

Run the simulation to the desired frame and then apply the Soft Body modifier in the modifiers tab. This will 'freeze' the current state of the soft body into the now static mesh.

[image: apply soft body]